# super.onBackPressed() and finish() exits the app

Tags: android

I have two activities viz; MyPostActivity and FeedReactionsActivity. 
I navigate from MyPostActivity to FeedReactionsActivity using intent.

Following is the code for going back.

```
btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finish();
            }
        });
```

and

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

But instead of going back the app exits. I think the MyPostActivity is being removed from the Activity Stack.

How do I check if that's the case? If not, why does my app exits?

EDIT : Added code that navigates from MyPostActivity to FeedReactionsActivity.

```
// Set click listeners
                vh1.cvContentHolder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MyPostActivity.this, FeedReactionsActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("mainFeedThumbnailDTO", thumbnailDTO);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
```

EDIT 2 : Manifest code

```
<activity
            android:name="com.hootout.MyPostActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.FullScreen.White"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"
            android:noHistory="true"/>

<activity
            android:name="com.hootout.FeedReactionsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_feed_reactions"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.FullScreen.Dark" />
```

I found my mistake. I set android:noHistory="true" 
App works fine after removing it.

Comment: Could you show the exact code for starting FeedReactionsActivity ?

Comment: Can you also include the code from the `MyPostActivity` activity class which navigates to the next activity?

Comment: The App will only exit if nothing's in the activity stack

Comment: Can you share your menifest code

Comment: @ShivamKumar Thanks for pointing out to check the manifest. It solved my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

from the manifest (PostActivity). A value of noHistory="true" means that the activity will not leave a historical trace. It will not remain in the activity stack for the task, so the user will not be able to return to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you switch from MyPostActivity you call the finish() function there. If you do that then try removing the call

Comment: finish() isn't called in MyPostActivity. I just checked.

Answer (score 0):

I had android:noHistory="true" set for MyPostActivity in Manifest file.

Removed it and app doesn't exit anymore.